# MS SQL conditional stored procedure to return values in all cases

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I have MS SQL Stored Procedure that returns values from 3 simple tables as follow and need it to return a row for the product in all cases. 
I want to know if is it possible to get the value of BrandID in (T3) and if doesn't have a row for the product record returns a value of 0 for "BrandID"

T3 is like

ProductID --- BrandID

```
@iCategoryID int
AS
Begin
SELECT P.ProductID,P.CategoryID, C.ParentID, PC.BrandID FROM T1 P
JOIN T2 C ON P.CategoryID = C.CategoryID
JOIN T3 PC ON P.ProductID=PC.ProductID
WHERE P.CategoryID=@iCategoryID 
ORDER by P.ProductID Asc
End
GO
```

Comment: Put ISNULL(PC.BrandID, 0) instead of PC.BrandID
and the join of t3 should be a left join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `left outer join`:

```
SELECT P.ProductID,P.CategoryID, C.ParentID, PC.BrandID
FROM T1 P LEFT JOIN
     T2 C
     ON P.CategoryID = C.CategoryID  LEFT JOIN
     T3 PC
     ON P.ProductID = PC.ProductID
WHERE P.CategoryID = @iCategoryID
ORDER by P.ProductID Asc;
```

This will return `NULL` if there is no match for brand.  If you want `0` instead:

```
SELECT P.ProductID,P.CategoryID, C.ParentID, coalesce(PC.BrandID, 0) as BrandID
FROM T1 P LEFT JOIN
     T2 C
     ON P.CategoryID = C.CategoryID  LEFT JOIN
     T3 PC
     ON P.ProductID = PC.ProductID
WHERE P.CategoryID = @iCategoryID
ORDER by P.ProductID Asc;
```